# Python 3.8 Selenium Firefox error on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Linode)

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run selenium using python3.8 and firefox. Tried using the latest two geckodriver version. Getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/insurance_monitor/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/root/insurance_monitor/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/root/insurance_monitor/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/root/insurance_monitor/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/root/insurance_monitor/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

Comment: webdriver-manager could be your solution. Check doc here : https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Comment: I think i found the reason. I was trying to run on Cloud. Had to set it headless

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the reason is... I was trying to run on Cloud. Had to set it headless